# Search Bar disappear when typing

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a problem with my search bar. As I begin to type, my search bar disappears. I've tried many solutions that have been listed here but none of them worked. I've added the search bar right under my nav bar and on top of my custom collection view, however I did not add it to the header of my collection view nor did I add it to the nav bar. I also want to note that I've done most of my code programmatically.

Here are some of the methods that I have already tried:

```
func setupSearchController(){


        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Type Here..."
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
//        let text = searchController.searchBar.text
        searchController.isActive = false
//        searchController.searchBar.text = text
        self.searchController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        searchController.searchBar.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]



    }
```

[Before picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw66n.png)

[After typing picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqDiA.png)

Comment: Have you used the default search bar provided in xcode?

Comment: Probably you should print (NSLog) the frame of search bar when you start typing text. Also, did you observe this on keyboard opening or typing from keyboard?

Comment: @PersianBlue yes I've use the default search bar provided by xcode

Comment: @NeverHopeless I'm a newbie to swift. I didn't set observe, do I need to?

Comment: I've also added 2 pictures, hope this clarify what I was referring to

Comment: @henry.C Then why dont you use the search bar delegate methods? It will handle everything.

Comment: @PersianBlue which search bar delegate methods do I have to implement? And how does this solve my problem? It still doesn't answer why the search bar is disappearing after I click it.